# Use firebase with SQLCipher

Tags: sqlite, firebase, sqlcipher

I have an app that uses SQLCipher to read and write to crypted databases.

Wanting to use Firebase, I stumbled upon 2 problems:

Firstly, some ... thing added `-l"sqlite3"` to my `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjectName/Pods-ProjectName.debug.xcconfig` (and `release` too, ofc). Because of this, my app's SQLs were failing with error `file is encrypted or is not a database`.

I solved this by adding a `post_install` to my `Podfile` that removes those from all config files.

After doing this, a Firebase SQL started failing with error `no such table: s2dRmqIds`.

AFAIK, there is no way to use SQLite and SQLCipher in the same project, as they are complementary.

Any idea what is Firebase trying to save in that table? Or how much of a problem is? Or if I can change the storing mechanism? Or if it is a (known) bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a same issue, after several hours, found a [SOLUTION]!

[image]

- Go to **Project Build Settings**
- Search for **Other Linker Flags**
- add line `-framework SQLCipher`

And that's it!)

Now Firebase and SQLCipher will live together happy.

Comment: Well, my solution was to stop using Firebase, but I trust you that this works so I'll accept it.

Comment: This shows builds setting error post pod install for other installed pods.

Answer (score 1):

I create a post install script that remove the -l"sqlite3" other linker flag from firebase pods and it helps!

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
      xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
      new_xcconfig = xcconfig.gsub('-l"sqlite3"', '')
      File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << new_xcconfig }
    end
  end
end
```